# How do I tell sendmail to use localhost port 2525 as a smart relay?

Tags: sendmail

I have a remote system setup on a very restrictive network. Unfortunately I have yet to find a way to have them run an email relay, or to allow the system to connect out to send mail.

There is no way to connect in, instead the system connects out using SSH (which happens via an HTTPS proxy) and uses the -R flag to forward a port on our system back to the remote system so we login.

I am not aware of a way to have sendmail use a https proxy for outbound connections. Instead, I have used -L to forward localhost:2525 to our mail server, but I can't work out how to have sendmail use this as its smart relay.

I have the following in my mc file

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `[10.10.22.4]')
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')
```

10.10.22.4 is the system's IP address, I also tried 127.0.0.1 with identical results..

The maillog looks like..

```
Jun 16 06:50:36 remotehost sm-mta[49702]: starting daemon (8.12.9p2): SMTP+queueing@00:30:00
Jun 16 06:50:36 remotehost sm-msp-queue[49703]: starting daemon (8.12.9p2): queueing@00:30:00
Jun 16 06:51:52 remotehost sendmail[50072]: r5G6poHi050072: from=user, size=46, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201306160651.r5G6poHi050072@remotehost>, relay=user@localhost
Jun 16 06:51:54 remotehost sm-mta[50129]: r5G6pqM2050129: from=<user@remotehost>, size=373, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201306160651.r5G6poHi050072@remotehost>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=Daemon0, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun 16 06:51:54 igarashi1 sendmail[50072]: r5G6poHi050072: to=user@outside.host, ctladdr=user (19999/19999), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=30041, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r5G6pqM2050129 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun 16 06:52:05 remotehost sm-mta[50137]: r5G6pqM2050129: to=<user@outside.host>, ctladdr=<user@remotehost> (19999/19999), delay=00:00:11, xdelay=00:00:11, mailer=esmtp, pri=30368, relay=mail.outside.host. [203.31.81.10], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail.outside.host.
```

ie it appears to ignore the smart relay part. Yes, I have checked the cf file is changing :) I  have also restarted sendmail completely (not just sent it a HUP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested Fix:**
Specify mailer in smart host definition:

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `relay:[10.10.22.4]')
```

**Explanation:**
I assume `[10.10.22.4]` is an IP address of local IP inteface. It makes it listed on sendmail's list of local email domain (`$=w`). Sendmail ignores "mailer-less" relays to names/addresses listed in `$=w`. (Sendmail does it in MailerToTriple rule set).

Comment: Yes, 10.10.22.4 is an address of the ethernet card. So is the 'relay:' part magical and forces it to use that address to relay? (Trying to work out how what you have differs from what I have tried)

Comment: The link came back so I could try it, and indeed it works. That you very much :)

Comment: It seems to be a precaution against a quite common class of sendmail's misconfigurations. Most likely it was made **LONG** time ago :-)

Comment: Too much dead chicken voodoo in sendmail <sigh>